# 1:N implementation in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Assume 2 columns in table `state_info`.

```
state       |  district
------------+---------------
Karnataka   |  Bangalore
Karnataka   |  Belgium
Karnataka   |  Mysore
Mumbai      |  Sandra
Mumbai      |  Madeira
```

I want to output them in a single column

```
Karnataka
Bangalore
Belgium
Mysore

Mumbai
Sandra
Madeira
```

state below that its dist ,again state below its dist

Comment: RESULT SHOULD BE IN 1 COLUMN LIKE ....STATE DIST,DIST2,STATE DIST1,DIST2...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT CONCAT(state, ', ', district) FROM state_info;
```

to get

```
Karnataka, Bangalore
Karnataka, Belgium
Karnataka, Mysore
Mumbai, Sandra
Mumbai, Madeira
```

Comment: i want all dist for that particular state in 1 column like                                                                                                                     karnataka
Mysore
bgm
mangalore

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Select Distinct(state) from Table1
UNION 
Select Distinct(district) from Table1;
```

the result will be

```
Bangalore
Belgium
Mysore
Sandra
Madeira
Karnataka
Mumbai
```

Comment: I want all dist below state this should repeat for all state .......but here in your query states and dist are separate

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
 Select Distinct(state) as data from Table1
 UNION 
 Select Distinct(district) as data from Table1;
) order by  data
```